# Magnetic forces on a small current-loop in an inhomogeneous magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current, education

I'm wondering why the [magnetic forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field#Force_on_moving_charges_and_current) on a rectangular small current-loop of side $\delta x$ and $\delta y$, lying in the $xy$ plane are the following ones ([Eq.(18) of "Small Current-Loops"](https://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/CDHW/EM/CW960430-2.pdf)):

$$
F_x = I \, \delta y \, B_z (x + \delta x) − I \, \delta y \, Bz (x) \\ = I \, \delta y \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial x} \, \delta x = m \, \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial x}
$$

I tried to get them by using the [Laplace's force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force#Force_on_a_current-carrying_wire) (also [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/540496/whats-the-difference-between-laplace-force-and-lorentz-force)) formula ($d\boldsymbol{l} = (\delta x, \, \delta x, \, 0)^T$):

$$
F(x, y, z) = I \, d\boldsymbol{l} \, \times \, \boldsymbol{B} = I \begin{pmatrix}
B_z \, \delta y \\
- B_z \, \delta x \\
B_y \, \delta x - B_x \, \delta y
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the I tried to evaluate:

$$F_x = F_x (x + \delta x) - F_x (x) = I \, B_z(x + \delta x) \, \delta y - I \,  B_z(x) \, \delta y $$

but this is wrong.

---

EDIT: the $F_y$, according to [eq. (18)](https://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/CDHW/EM/CW960430-2.pdf) is:

$$
F_y = I \, \delta x \, B_z (y + \delta y) − I \, \delta x \, Bz (y) \\ = I \, \delta x \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial y} \, \delta x = m \, \frac{\partial B_z}{\partial y}
$$

in this case maybe there are two mistakes (1) the last term should be $\delta y$, and (2) there should be a minus sign:

$$
F_y = - I \, \delta x \, \delta y \, \frac{\partial B_z(y)}{\partial y}
$$

The Taylor's expansion I applied is:

$$
B_z(y+\delta y)\simeq B_z(y)+\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial y}(y)\,\delta y
$$

if I apply it to the eq. 18, "it works" (*); instead, if I apply it to my equation (the component $- B_z(y) \, \delta x$ I reported in the above vector $F(x,y,z)$), it gives me a minus sign.

(*) Actually the term $\delta y$ doesn't appear in the final result and this is an error because it is wrong to write $m = I \, \delta x \, \delta x$; indeed in the equation of the $F_x$ we have $m = I \, \delta x \, \delta y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any mistake in your calculation, you're just missing the final step.

The Taylor expansion of $B_z$ to first order in the neighborhood of $x$ is:
$$B_z(x+\delta x)\simeq B_z(x)+\frac{\partial B_z}{\partial x}(x)\,\delta x$$
which yields the result you wanted.

Comment: You're refering to an equation (18) that doesn't exist in your question. Please make your question as self-contained as possible. Also, remember that the magnetic field is a function of three variables. In my answer I didn't write $y$ and $z$ because they weren't impacted by the Taylor expansion, but for other components of the force, you might need to write them explicitely.

Comment: Hi @Miyase I reported the $F_y$ from equation 18 in the above link in order to avoid to visit the webpage. I performed the same calculations as before because the $F_x$ and the $F_y$ have the same form. The only difference is that we should replace $x$ with $y$.

Comment: Then include the new equation in your post. Making an external link a required part of a question is frowned upon here, because the link could break in the future, making the question impossible to understand.

Comment: Second line, one of the $\delta x$ should be a $\delta y$ (you didn't apply Taylor expansion correctly).

Comment: I'd check sign consistency. I tried to draw a figure of your problem, you seem to have the current running in the "positive" direction of $x$ axis on the side $x+\delta x$, which would make it run in the "negative" direction of $y$ axis on the side $y+\delta y$. That would introduce a global minus sign for $F_y$.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: Make a careful drawing with the orientation of the current, and be careful with the orientation of vector $I\,d\vec{l}$ in Laplace force. Each of the four sides of the square must be studied separately.

Comment: Hello @Miyase can you take a look to this question please? https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/718140/difference-between-electromotive-force-and-back-electromotive-force