# Difference between electromotive force and back electromotive force

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, education

I'm wondering what is the difference between electromotive force EMG and back electromotive force BEMG.

I tried to answer in the following way by using two examples. but I'm not sure about the goodness of my examples.

**Example 1**: consider a circuit in which there isn't any current when the magnetic induction field $B$ is zero. When $B \neq 0$, according to the the Faraday's law, an EMG appears and thus there is a current. In this case the EMG is **not** against the current because the EMG is the cause of the current.

**Example 2**: consider a circuit in which there is a current when the magnetic induction field $B$ is zero. When $B \neq 0$, according to the the Faraday's law, an EMG appears and this EMG is **against** the original current. Is this the reason why in this case I can call EMG with the special name of BEMG?

Answer (score 0):

Electro-motive force (EMF) is a general physical term. Any voltage source that can provide a circulating current in a closed circuit can be regarded as an EMF source. For example a battery.

Back-Electromotive force (BEMF) is more like an engineering term. For example in a synchronous motor, when you spin the rotor, a voltage is induced in its windings. This is called BEMF. You could say that a BEMF is an external EMF resulting from electromagnetic induction that opposes your main voltage source. If energy loss is neglected, in steady-state, the BEMF is equal to the main EMF source that gives power to the motor. (Note that in this case there's no current but both EMF and BEMF are present).

In your examples there were some errors.

EMF appears only due to the time-change of magnetic flux, according to Faraday's law of induction:
$$e=\frac{d\phi}{dt}$$
Therefore it doesn't matter that flux $\phi$ is zero or not, what matters is its time-change. Also its has nothing to do with the magnitude of current in the loop. Only the time-change of this current is the source of self-induction (BEMF).

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I recommend to my student that they avoid focusing on current when using Lenz's law. Induction can be triggered by anything that makes the magnetic flux vary over time. It can be because of a current, because of a force, because of the magnetic field itself...

What matters is that the "fictious voltage" (the back electromotive force) given by Faraday's law will lead to a reaction that counters the cause.

If you have a circuit with no current, but you gave some initial velocity to a part of it, then the BEMF will be such that a force appears to counter that motion. To make that force act in the appropriate direction, the current needs to be traveling in a specific direction, and so on.

If you have a rigid, fixed circuit with a time-varying current, then the BEMF will be such that the variations are smoothed out, because it's those variations that triggered induction.

You can even have a BEMF in an open circuit where no current can travel, for instance in a current clamp.